# How to connect snowflake database to Teradata SQL assistant

Tags: python, odbc, teradata-sql-assistant, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm not able to connect snowflake database in Teradata SQL assistant.
I have already install ODBC Driver in my laptop. But still not able to define ODBC driver in  Teradata SQL assistant.

Can you please guide

Comment: Here is a suggestion from Angie Coleman (Snowflake Computing):  https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008aRncISAS/support-connecting-teradata-sql-assistant-to-snowflake

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit ODBC driver? What error are you encountering?